# How to Change the color of BASE of cone in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

My cone is shown as in the jsfiddle link. Right now whole cone is in single color that is blue. But I wanted to change the color of square base of cone to Red. For that I need to change color of two faces which form the Square base. How to do that?

JsFiddle link for My cone: http://jsfiddle.net/sagh0900/suvKg/1/

```
function getGeometry(meshMaterial)
{
var cone;
var geo = new THREE.Geometry();
geo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
geo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, 0.5, 1));
geo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0.5, 1));
geo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, -0.5, 1));
geo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0.5, -0.5, 1)); 
geo.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(0,1,2));
geo.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(2,1,4));
geo.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(1,3,4));
geo.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(4,3,0));
geo.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(3,1,0));
geo.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(0,2,4));
geo.computeFaceNormals();
cone = new THREE.Mesh(geo, meshMaterial);
cone.doubleSided = true;
cone.overdraw = true;
return cube;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign colors to the vertices and then use vertex colors in your material. For an example this process, look at the source code in the example:

http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Vertex-Colors.html